# How include css class based on post ( in loop ) slug?

Tags: posts, loop, filters

I'm using this function to retrieve body and single post classes from their slugs.

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'fl_pages_bodyclass' );
add_filter('body_class','fl_pages_bodyclass');
function fl_pages_bodyclass($classes) {
    if (is_page() || is_single() ) {
        // get page slug
        global $post;
        $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;

        // add slug to $classes array
        $classes[] = $slug;
        // return the $classes array
        return $classes;
    } else { 
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

This function is working fine, but I would like to include posts inside loops. I've tried removing `if(is_ ..)`. Then it is working, but a problem arises on a 404 page - I got “Trying to get property of non-object in” error - so I've tried to exclude 404 page by

```
if (is_404() ) {
     return $classes;
     }
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Or how can I include posts in loops?

Comment: Where did you put that 404-test?

Comment: `add_filter( 'post_class', 'fl_pages_bodyclass' );
add_filter('body_class','fl_pages_bodyclass');
function fl_pages_bodyclass($classes) {
        // get page slug
        global $post;
        $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;
 
        // add slug to $classes array
        $classes[] = $slug;
        // return the $classes array
        return $classes;
     
 if (is_404() ) {
     return $classes;
     }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is produced by `$slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;` because there is no `post_name` on a 404 page. So, to prevent this error you must structure the function in a way it doesn't get to this line when it is called on a 404-page. Like this:

```
add_filter ('post_class', 'fl_pages_bodyclass');
add_filter ('body_class', 'fl_pages_bodyclass');
function fl_pages_bodyclass ($classes) { 
  global $post;
  if (!is_404()) {
    $slug = get_post($post)->post_name; 
    $classes[] = $slug;
    }
  return $classes;
  }
```